# VCalendar. Is it possible vcalendar title to use locale language but date names still in English?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using vue 3 with vcalendar plugin. Is there a way I can apply locale to vcalendar's title and keep the date names in English?

I have attached the image here.

[image: vcalendar image]

I tried to find a way on the doc and similar problems across the internet but I couldn't find a related problem.

Comment: It is not possible to create custom localization with the vcalendar library.  Other people have mentioned it in the library's github issues but the author has never taken any action on it.

Comment: [this PR](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/pull/940) by someone else apparently added the feature but they deleted their branch and closed the PR for unknown reasons, the commits with code changes are still there if you want to pick up the work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.